# C# network data stream processing

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, character, byte

When C# processes network data streams, the encoding of the data stream is often not fixed and may be unknown. If you want to replace a certain section of English letters in the data stream, such as removing the last (0.02 secs) in the data stream, using C# you need to convert the bytes array of the network data stream into a string through a known encoding , and then use regular or string functions to process it. But as mentioned just now, when the bytes array is converted to a string, an error will occur if the encoding is unknown.
Python3 is based on bytes type programming. When Python processes data streams, it does not need to convert bytes data directly into strings according to a certain encoding for post-processing. Python's string functions can directly operate on bytes data without converting bytes into strings according to a certain encoding, such as:

```
import re


# Assume that networkdata is a data packet obtained from the network, and the encoding in the data packet is unknown
# The requirement only needs to replace (0.02 secs). The ending English numeric characters
# Do not try to use decode or the like to convert a certain encoding into str type
networkdata = b"The data obtained from the Internet (0.02 secs).\r\n"
if networkdata.strip().endswith(b" (0.02 secs)."):
    networkdata = re.sub(rb"\s\([0-9+.]+\ssecs\)\.\r\n$", b'\r\n', networkdata, 1)
print(networkdata)  # Network data is sent out
```

The above python can easily operate on the bytes type directly without knowing the encoding. I would like to ask, does C# perform operations similar to the above-mentioned python on the data stream when the encoding is unknown?

I hope to be able to master the solution to such problems in C#.